# VB.net disable CompareValidator from code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, requiredfieldvalidator

Is it possible to disable `CompareValidator  / RequiredFieldValidator` from code behind in VB.net?

I have 3 field (dropdown and two dated picker) and **once the month from dropdown is selected I want to disable validation / required on datepicker inputs**.

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Please note  have already tried this, and it does not work:

```
Protected Sub DashbodropardMonthsDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DashbodropardMonthsDropDown.SelectedIndexChanged
        ' If Month is selected from DD menu
        Dim MonthDD As Integer = DashbodropardMonthsDropDown.SelectedValue

        ' If nothing selected or selected "--select" with value 0
        If MonthDD = 0 Then

            'Validate DatePicker
            CompareValidatorT1.Enabled = True
            RequiredFieldValidator2.Enabled = True
            RequiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = True

        Else

            'Do Not Validate DatePicker
            CompareValidatorT1.Enabled = False
            RequiredFieldValidator2.Enabled = False
            RequiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = False


        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable or disable your Validators from `code behind` by doing something like this

```
CompValidator.Enabled=false
```

**EDIT:**
Setting `AutoPostBack=true` for the `DropDownList` helped

Comment: Already tried. As the Validator is injected with JS, the JS is always first to run.

Comment: @NewUser Do you want to disable it with JS?

Comment: Not really, I would prefer to disable this from code behind - hence the title of the question. Plus the condition of something selected from DD is very important.

Comment: @NewUser Did you set your Dropdownlist AutoPostBack property to true?

Comment: Working with AutoPostBack! Thanks! Is it possible to do this without the postback? As this cause update panel reload.

Comment: @NewUser You will then have to use javascript , because the selectedindexchanged event only works if the autopostback property is set to true.